# Force locale not taking affect in Toolbar content

Tags: java

I am using code-below to change locale. It is already a day trying to change my locale but no success yet.

```
Locale locale;

    public void changeLanguage(Locale localeChanger){
        locale=localeChanger;
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, displayMetrics);

        Intent refreshStartPage = new Intent(this, StartPage.class);
        startActivity(refreshStartPage);
        recreate();
    }
```

and here my Toolbar xml code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/page_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of text line inside Toolbar layout

```
android:text="title"
```

Then add

```
setTitle (R.string.name_here)
```

inside your Toolbar initializing method. Hope, you got what you want.